# Then And The Sentence

Tags: grammar

I've been struggling with an independent clause question:

> I always run at night, and then I go see my nephew.

Would a comma go before "and"? I wasn't sure if "then I go see my nephew" would be considered an independent clause. I know "then" is an adverb, but I'm not sure if I can start a sentence with it.

Comment: You don't need the comma.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, or you can omit the subject in the second clause:

> I always run at night and then go see my nephew.

Also, the rule of thumb is that a comma is a pause is a comma, so if you pause there you should probably put a comma to indicate it.

Looking *then* up in Merriam-Webster, I didn't see anything I could cite, but their [Learner's Dictionary](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/definition/then) gives some example sentences starting with it.

Comment: You've changed the sentence by omitting the 'then'.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Yes, I wasn't sure how to write that while staying on-topic. A second look reveals a flaw in my thinking, however; edited.